# where is ejabberd.cfg file available ? How to change db from mnesia to mySQL in windows os?

Tags: ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd.I am using ejabberd 15.07 vesion. I want to change the defeault db from mnesia to mySQL server on windows platform.

I came across that we need to do some modifications on ejabberd.cfg file.
Which directory this file is available? please answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will found in lot of documentations which says to modify the `ejabberd.cfg` file. As per the new releases of ejabberd, the ejabberd.cfg is deprecated. The configuration file for ejabberd is `ejabberd.yml`. You can find the [Config File Formatting](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#config-file-formatting) in the docs which says the ejabberd configuration file must have `.yml` or `.yaml` extension. Directory of this ejabberd config file will be `etc` directory.

You can change the database to MySQL as:

1) First you need to compile ejabberd with the MySQL support like:

```
./configure --enable-odbc --enable-mysql
```

2) Create the tables using the supplied script

```
mysql < /path/to/mysql.sql
```

3) Comment your `internal` authentication method (`auth_method`) and add the ODBC authentication method

```
# auth_method: internal ## Commented this line
auth_method: ODBC ## Added this line
```

4) Then you need to have a connection to MySQL.

```
odbc_type: mysql
odbc_server: "localhost"
odbc_port: 3306 # the default
odbc_database: "mydb"
odbc_username: "user1"
odbc_password: "userpassword"
odbc_pool_size: 5
```

You can read the description for the options [here](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#relational-databases)

5) Add `_odbc` to modules you wish to use the odbc database

```
mod_offline_odbc instead of mod_offline
```

6) Restart the ejabberd server

Comment: Thanks Yashwanth,,, I tried from 2 to 6 th steps,, now first step is to compile with that command,, is that command works on windows os or only Linus os....?

Comment: @AkPanda It will work with the both and not OS dependent. We are enable the odbc connection and compiling with the MySQL support. So It is unique for all the OS's

Comment: Thank youfor your answer,Yaswant,.I have installed ejabberd 15.07 binary installer.I did not install it by compiling source code distribution archive.To integrate mysql i did the changes in ejabberd.yml file. I am not able to compile that ejabberd with mysql support and after restarting ejabberd i am getting error in logs that " Cannot load c:/../ejabberd/..../conf/ejabberd.yml: Syntax error on line 245 at position 4: did not find expected '-' indicator"...My line 245 is auth_method: odbc. can you tell me how to compile ejabberd binary installer for MYSQL support.

Comment: @AkParida You have a syntax error at line 245. you may be missing the indentation. Please check

Comment: Thank you Yaswant ,, I solved that indentation problem.now i am getting this below error in erl_crash_20150819-120255.dump file. the error is ,,,, Wed Aug 19 12:03:04 2015
Slogan: Problem starting the module mod_pubsub_odbc for host <<"aswini-pc">> 
 options: [{access_createnode,pubsub_createnode},
           {ignore_pep_from_offline,true},
           {last_item_cache,false}, can you tell me why it is happening??

Comment: @AkParida Some of the modules may be having problem to start if you add `_odbc` to the module. Because some may be global which can be directly access the ODBC connection. So no need to add `_odbc` for the modules of that kind. You can remove `_odbc` for `mod_pubsub_odbc` in your config file

Comment: Yes Yeswanth,, Iexactly did that, now i am able to integrate mysql with ejabberd .many many thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Glad to hear that... Its my pleasure.. you can upvote my answer though if you found good

Comment: I have a new situation,,Now i want to authenticate users from mysql server but from other custom database. before i was authenticating using ejabberd db(imported ejabberd.sql to mysql).I can see in ejabberd.logs,that each time it does authentication,it is making a query for the user,i.e. Select password from users where username is "admin" .Can i modify this query to authenticate users from my other db in mysql server.Not getting the path where this auth query is available?

Comment: I can change the db by following above steps but i think it will not fetch my users table,,as the table name is different....So can you tell me the steps to change db from ejabberd to other custom db....

Comment: I am unable to get your point. Are you asking for the external authentication using MySQL? please get in touch with me through my mail id `yashwanthbabu.gujarathi@gmail.com`. Let's discuss more about this